# Rails pulling attributes in an observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observers

I have this observer which monitors the Comments table and will send an email after something is created.  It doesn't seem that I'm doing the associations correctly in the observer though because I receive an error or `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 5)):` using this code:

```
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(comment)

    if comment.guest_comment == true
      if comment.name?
        InvoiceMailer.message(comment.name, comment.content, comment.email, comment.user.email, comment.order_id).deliver
      elsif comment.email?
        # do something if there's no email yet
        InvoiceMailer.message(comment.name, comment.content, comment.order.customer.email, comment.user.email, comment.order_id).deliver
      else
        InvoiceMailer.message(comment.email, comment.content, comment.email, comment.user.email, comment.order_id).deliver
      end
    else
      # owner made the comment
      if comment.user.account.company_name?
        InvoiceMailer.message(comment.user.name+", "+comment.user.account.company_name, comment.content, comment.user.email, comment.email, comment.order_id).deliver
      else  
        InvoiceMailer.message(comment.user.name, comment.content, comment.user.email, comment.email, comment.order_id).deliver
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to write correct associations inside an observer?

Answer (score 0):

So I found that that observers don't/shouldn't have access to the database.  I moved my logic to the mailer for now (will move to a helper later).  Then make sure not to use "message" as your method name since it's reserved ;)